# Really annoying keyboard screw up when entering sqlplus

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tty

Often when using bash I am used to using the keys ^A and ^E to go to the 
beginning and end of line, and the arrow keys to move from character to 
character without erasing.  Every now and then, I enter certain tools 
where it completely screws up my hotkeys, and nothing works.  My keyboard 
is remapped making the delete key the backspace key, ^W now erases words 
and it is impossible for me to correct anything in the command line 
because just about every key for editing the commands typed puts garbage 
characters to the terminal.  This often happens to me when entering 
passwords or SQLPlus in a UNIX terminal.

I don't even know if this is bash or something else, but someone told me
too look at this command:

```
  $ stty -a
  speed 38400 baud; rows 37; columns 100; line = 0;
  intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^Z;
  start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0
  ;
  -parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
  -ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel

  opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
  isig icanon iexten echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop -echoctl -echoke
```

Anyhow, I don't know what I am looking at here, but I do recognize some of 
the shortcuts ^W and ^U.  How can I redefine things to make this weird 
terminal settings act like regular bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you describe is provided by readline, so if the utility you are using doesn't support readline or something equivalent you are out of luck. The terminal only interprets a very limited set of escape codes, mainly the ones for deleting the previous word (^W) and for deleting the whole line (^U), for the rest (^A, ^E, ...) the application has to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `reset` command, in the `ncurses` package.

If you rather mean inside of `sqlplus`, then the other answer is correct: there's nothing you can do, because `sqlplus` is an ancient and doesn't support `readline`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant that your terminal got screwed up outside of sqlplus. If you mean inside of sqlplus, then ninjalj is correct: there's nothing you can do, because sqlplus is an ancient piece of crap that doesn't use readline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rlwrap](http://freecode.com/projects/rlwrap)

Unfortunately, if you are on client site, you can't compile it. But you can [download a binary version here](http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/static-version-of-rlwrap-for-sqlplus/%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B2%5D)

Have fun!